# Providing initial data for a many-to-many table in Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, many-to-many

I want to clarify the format of providing initial data in raw SQL for a Django model that uses a many to many relationship. I've based my query on [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/). I know I'm not required to specify the `through` parameter in ManyToManyField for this case, but I would like to have the table listed explicitly.

Backend db is MySQL & table names are lowercase Class names.

**Model :**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')
    
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

I suppose the correct way to provide data would be :

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Ringo Starr')
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Paul McCartney')

INSERT INTO group VALUES ('The Beatles')

INSERT INTO membership VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO membership VALUES (2, 1)
```

How will I specify this data if I did not declare the Membership table explicitly and didn't use the `through` parameter? Is the following correct?

```
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Ringo Starr')
INSERT INTO person VALUES ('Paul McCartney')
```

> <strike>INSERT INTO group VALUES ('The Beatles', 1)</strike>
> <strike>INSERT INTO group VALUES ('The Beatles', 1)</strike>

UPDATE : The second method isn't correct. The `members` field under `Group` class isn't a real dB column.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

The correct way to do it in SQL is the same as when you use `through`, but the table that was `membership` before will either have a name generated by Django like `person_group_a425b`, or a name you specify with the `db_table` parameter on `Group.members`.

More details:

Even if you don't make a model explicitly for the table that joins them together, Django will create a join table for them.

[From the Django docs about how the table is named](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#id1):

> Behind the scenes, Django creates an intermediary join table to represent the 
>   many-to-many relationship. By default, this table name is generated using the name of 
>   the many-to-many field and the name of the table for the model that contains it. Since 
>   some databases don’t support table names above a certain length, these table names will 
>   be automatically truncated to 64 characters and a uniqueness hash will be used. This 
>   means you might see table names like author_books_9cdf4; this is perfectly normal.

You can provide a shorter/different name for the join table in the definition of the ManyToManyfield, using the [db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.db_table) option.